# vlcj get metadata from rtsp stream

Tags: java, vlc, rtsp, vlcj

I want to get metadata from RTSP stream with vlcj. The RTSP stream has no video and audio data. There is only metadata that has analytical info. When I start it  crashes and shuts down. Error in log file 'Failed to setup RTSP session'.
How can I get the metadata file with vlcj?

```
    String[] VLC_ARGS = {
            "--intf", "dummy",          // no interface
            "--vout", "dummy",          // we don't want video (output)
            "--no-audio",               // we don't want audio (decoding)
    };
    MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory(VLC_ARGS);
    
    EmbeddedMediaListPlayerComponent mediaPlayerComponent = new EmbeddedMediaListPlayerComponent();

    // Create player.
    HeadlessMediaPlayer mediaPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.newHeadlessMediaPlayer();

    // Select input device.
    String mrl = "rtsp://user:pass@192.168.1.90/axis-media/media.amp?video=0&audio=0&event=off&analytics=polygon";
    
    mediaPlayer.playMedia(mrl);
    mediaPlayer.addMediaPlayerEventListener(new MediaPlayerEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void mediaMetaChanged(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int metaType) {
            System.out.println("metadata changed");
    
        }

    }
```

Comment: If you use the "vlc" command directly, with the exact value of the "mrl" variable you posted, does it start playing anything or does it "crash" in the same way?

Comment: Also, try including "-vvv" in those VLC_ARGS and inspecting the logs for the reason for the failure.

Comment: I try with vlc command direcly and get same error. "satip error: Failed to setup RTSP session"

Comment: Well that's the thing you need to fix, it's not a vlcj problem. If you can get it working with vlc, I can tell you how to get it working with vlcj.